# Rails 5 with Puma not reloading code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I have a Rails application running on Puma.
I am not using multiple workers on development and `cache_classes` is set to `false` in `development.rb`
I also uninstalled `spring`.

However, Rails does not acknowledge code changes so I always have to restart the server.

Could it be some of my gems that are causing this?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.5.0"

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'

gem 'timecop'
gem 'appsignal'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'elasticsearch'
gem "hashie", "3.4.6"
gem "awesome_print"
gem 'foreman'
gem 'dry-logic', '0.3.0'
gem 'dry-container', '0.3.4'
gem 'dry-types', '0.8.0'
gem 'grape'
gem 'grape-jbuilder'
gem 'grape-swagger'
gem 'grape-swagger-rails'
gem 'hstore-attributes'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'nested-hstore'
gem 'net-sftp'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-status'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpack-rails'

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rack-timeout', '0.4.2'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  # Load vars in .env
  begin
    gem 'dotenv-rails', require: 'dotenv/rails-now'
    require 'dotenv'
    Dotenv.load
  rescue LoadError
  end
end

group :test do
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rspec-its'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

environments/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = true
    Bullet.alert = true
    Bullet.bullet_logger = true
    Bullet.console = true
    Bullet.rails_logger = true
  end
  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  # We don't use ActiveRecord
  # # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  # config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = false

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: You should also have "config.assets.compile = true" in your dev environment file.

Comment: What code changes are you making? Some of them like initialisers require a server reboot whereas views etc usually don't.

Comment: @ThorTL67 of course, I am talking about app/ code changes.

Comment: @bkunzi01 yeah but this is unrelated to the code reload issue.

Comment: All the sub-folders of `app` don't autoload or only particular one?

Comment: All the subfolders of app unfortunately